# Why won't apache bind to port 80 on Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: apache-http-server, windows-10, port

I just upgraded to Windows 10 and now Apache won’t start complaining that port 80 is in use.

```
NetStat -a -b
```

Says that it can’t figure out what process is using port 80.

How do I find out and kill it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious solution I had discounted.

When running Windows 7 I had turned off the IIS service (which obviously uses port 80). The Windows 10 upgrade turns it back on.

I turned it off again and all is well.